NIFI:Extract filename using NIFI and store the filenames in a single file
I'm new to NiFi.
I've been working on reading multiple files using ListFile and FetchFile processors. Now, I want to extract the filenames from those files and store all of them in a CSV file that includes the filename and the system date when it was read.
I'm using NIFI 1.20.0.
I've attempted to use the UpdateAttribute processor to create new attributes containing the filename and the system date. Then, I tried to convert the records into a CSV file using the ConvertRecord processor, but it didn't yield the desired result. Instead, I only got the content of the file.
